# how to combine three values in one column in database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating one database in my application with name *journey* and table name *userinformation* and userjourney
In *userinformation* I have six columns. The column name is *userid*, *divceid* ,*firstname*, *lastname* and *extra*.

But in my *userjourney* table I have three columns that are *journeyid*, *userid* and *information* this much only.

I dont have problems to save this stuff in database. It's working properly.

I have a problem with the *journeyid* column because I have to save three values in the *journeyid* column.
I have to save data in *journeyid* column like this `:-userid&divceid&timestamp`. I have to show this value together in one column.

How can I do? Please help me, friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already have the values of userid, divceid and timestamp in string variables (since you are inserting them in an array).

Just concatenate the three strings, create a single string from this and save it as journeyid.

```
NSString *journeyid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@&%@", userid, divceid, timestamp];
//save this string variable to the database table in the journeyid column
```

I hope this is what you are looking for (not entirely sure though)

If you want to get the timestamp, use

```
NSDate *dt = [NSDate date]; //get current date
NSString *timestamp = [dt description]; //get date in string format. Use NSDateFormatter if you want the date in a specific format
```

Comment: i get the date in string format.i want the date to be in int format

Comment: so you want to get the string as number of seconds? Use NSDate's timeIntervalSince1970 method. That returns NSTimeInterval which is typedef double.

Answer (score 0):

You can save these three values in one column separated by comma like this,

userid,divceid,timestamp

using this technique you can easily save and retrieve these values.

Comment: how to do this please give me some example on this data

Comment: if you are able to get userid, deviceid and timestamp in some NSString variable then you made a string as i mentioned above by using 'stringByAppendingString' or 'appendString' method. And then save this string to your 'journeyid' column.

Comment: friend i get only two value useridand deviceid i dont get timestamp how can i gat this timestamp please help

Comment: for timeStamp use this,                               NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
                                       
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];